# Exception handling in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a method that checks for broken links:

```
def self.check_prod_links
  require 'net/http'
  results = []
  Product.find_each(:conditions =>{:published => 1}) do |product|
    url = product.url 
    id = product.id
    uri = URI(url)
    begin
      response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    rescue
      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      http.use_ssl = true
      http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
      response = http.request(request)
    rescue
      response = Net::HTTP.get_response("http://" + uri)  
    rescue => e
      p "Problem getting url: #{url} Error Message: #{e.message}"
    end
    p "Checking URL = #{url}. ID = #{id}. Response Code = #{response.code}" 
    unless response.code.to_i == 200
      product.update_attribute(:published, 0) 
      results << product
    end
  end
  return results
end
```

My understanding was that rescue => e should log all exceptions not caught by the previous rescue statements, and the method should continue running, however for some reason when certain URL's are checked, the script quits with the following exception:

> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A:
>   unknown protocol

How can I set this up so that if an exception is caught, it will be printed, and the task will continue running?

Also, how can I call the results array to render in the mailer view, is there a better way to do this so that I can add all products that were unpublished to an already existing mailer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your first rescue will be the only one that works. Specifying `=> e` just tells Ruby to store the exception in a variable called `e`. I'm thinking the code in your first rescue block is raising the error you are seeing and there is nothing else rescuing it. To be honest, this is kind of a mess of code and you might be better off refactoring it into smaller methods.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot rescue like that, because all you rescues escapes all exceptions. You can have nested rescues like this:

```
    require 'net/http'

    def check_prod_links
      url = 'http://githuasdasdab.com'
      uri = URI(url)
      begin
        puts '1'
        response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
        puts '2'
      rescue
        begin
          puts '3'
          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true
          http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
          request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
          response = http.request(request)
          puts '4'
        rescue
          begin
            puts '5'
            response = Net::HTTP.get_response("http://" + uri)
            puts '6'
          rescue => e
            puts '7'
            p "Problem getting url: #{url} Error Message: #{e.message}"
          end
        end
      end
      puts '8'
      if response
        p "Checking URL = #{url}. Response Code = #{response.code}"
        unless response.code.to_i == 200
        end
      end
    end

    check_prod_links
```

it produces

```
    1
    3
    5
    7
    "Problem getting url: http://githuasdasdab.com Error Message: can't convert URI::HTTP into String"
    8
```

Comment: and I agree with @beerlington it's a mess, you should not do it that way